# The meaning of the word,"scalp"

Tags: word-usage

> The part down the center of her hair is a crooked lightning bolt of white scalp.

Source: Fight Club by Chuck Palahniuk

Cabmbridge Advanced Dictionary tells me that, "scalp" is the skin on the top of a person's head where hair usually grows.

But I don't think that Marla Singer was bald.

Comment: You understand what the word **part** means, in the context of head of hair?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps her hair has a [***parting***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parting) *(the line where a person's hair is separated down the centre)* through which the scalp can be seen.

Comment: Where is *down the center*? I am struggling to understand the position of "down the center of her hair"

Comment: It's the prime-meridian of her head.  :) https://www.google.com/search?q=center+hair+part&num=20&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidptfcr_PNAhWBox4KHQsuAkcQ_AUICCgB&biw=1411&bih=1040&dpr=0.9  There's a yellow line **down the center** of the road.

Comment: @Cardinal: See [these pictures](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hair+parting&hl=en&biw=1114&bih=820&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPnqSes_PNAhXB6xoKHePMBMoQsAQIIQ)

Comment: @TRomano :)) I understood that. But, I was curious to know what does "down the center" means, especially what does "down" do in that phrase.

Comment: **down** there is synonymous with **running|moving|existing along**.  He ran down the street.  There's a gash running down his cheek.  The factory has an assembly line running down the center of the building.